# File operations with error indicator set

Tags: c

I have to individually read characters and substrings from a stream in C while parsing them. I wish also to check for input error. The obvious way to do this is something like:

```
c = fgetc(f);
if(ferror(f)) {
    puts(strerror(errno));
    exit(1);
}
/* do something with c */
c = fgetc(f);
if(ferror(f)) {
    puts(strerror(errno));
    exit(1);
}
/* do something with c */
```

Etc. However, it would be much more practical and fast (in the non-exceptional case when there's no error) if I could do all the input operations and check for the error indicator later:

```
c = fgetc(f);
/* do something with c */
c = fgetc(f);
/* do something with c */
if(ferror(f)) {
    puts(strerror(errno));
    exit(1);
}
```

This would be possible if input operations like fgetc(), scanf() etc were simple passthrough no-ops when the error indicator of f is set. Say, an error occours in the first fgetc() and therefore the second fgetc() is a no-op that fails but change neither the error indicator of f nor errno.

A similiar question may be asked about output functions.

My question is: is this the behaviour of stdio functions? May I check ferror(f) after all operations and get errno then if I am sure that all those "do something with c" do not change errno?

Thanks!

Comment: You could write a `myfgetc` function that does what you describe.

Comment: Sure, a wrapper function. An obvious solution!

Comment: The subsequent function calls fail, but other functions may also change the value of `errno` — whether they failed or not.  So, you lose accurate tracking of `errno` with your proposed scheme, but it otherwise works.

Comment: There is no reason to ever call `ferror` until `fgetc` returns EOF.

Comment: @William Pursell There is nothing wrong in calling ferror() even if fgetc() does not return EOF. if ferror() is set, then I know that fgetc() returned EOF.

Comment: The only thing wrong with calling `ferror` this way is that you aren't checking if fgetc returned EOF, so you don't actually know if you've gotten any data.  I suppose you could call `ferror` and then check if c == EOF, or check `feof`, but doing so is extremely non-idiomatic.

Comment: "if ferror() is set, then I know that fgetc() returned EOF." --> No.  `ferror()` returns the state of the _error indicator_ for the file.  `ferror()` is true means that at sometime in the past, an error occurred, not necessarily the previous `*get()` - perhaps even long ago.

Answer (score 0):

No, those are not the defined semantics of `errno`.

Quoting [this manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/errno):

> Its value is significant only when the return value of the call indicated an error (i.e., `-1` from most system calls; `-1` or `NULL` from most library functions); a function that succeeds is allowed to change errno.

This implies that if you were to do two I/O operations where the first fails, and the second is a "no-op" (like read zero bytes) it could succeed and opt to clear `errno`, thus dropping the error set by the first call.

Comment: I think that if the error indicator for f is set, all subsequent calls of fgetc(f) should fail. Am I wrong? My hope is that errno gets untouched in such cases.

Comment: @user1542207 *My hope is that errno gets untouched in such cases.*  You plan on writing code based on *hope*?

Comment: @Andrew Henle No, I plan to write code based on specifications that's what I came here looking for. But the first step is always hope.

Comment: No function in the standard C library (or standard POSIX [library](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/errno.html)) sets `errno` to zero. The C11 standard says: _The value of `errno` in the initial thread is zero at program startup (the initial value of `errno` in other threads is an indeterminate value), but is never set to zero by any library function. The value of `errno` may be set to nonzero by a library function call whether or not there is an error, provided the use of `errno` is not documented in the description of the function in this International Standard._

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, it seems that the reliable way to implement what I was looking for is to write a wrapper function myfgetc(), as  Michael Walz suggested, together with a global variable myerrno:

```
__thread int myerrno = 0;

int myfgetc(FILE *f) {
    int c;
    if(myerrno)
        return EOF;
    if((c = fgetc(f)) == EOF)
        myerrno = errno;
    return c;
}
```

The storage class __thread is added to myerrno so that every thread has its own myerrno. It can be ommited if the program is single threaded.

Answer (score 0):

> ...is this (an error occurs in the first fgetc() and therefore the second fgetc() is a no-op that fails) the behaviour of stdio functions?

No - not a no-op.

`FILE` has: "an error indicator that records whether a read/write error has occurred,"  (C11dr § § 7.21.1 2), not that an error *just* occurred.  It is a flag that accumulates the history of read errors.

For `fgetc()` and friends,

> If a read error occurs, the error indicator for the stream is set and the `fgetc` function returns `EOF`.  C11dr § 7.21.7.1 3.

This return of `EOF` due to input error differs from `EOF` due to end-of-file.  The latter has an **or** "If the end-of-file indicator for the stream is set, **or** if the stream is at end-of-file, the end-of-file indicator for the stream is set and the `fgetc` function returns `EOF`".  `EOF` due to input error does not have an **or**.

I interpret this to imply that the *error indicator* of the stream can be true and `fgetc()` does not return `EOF` as the byte just read was not in error.

[How a stream error indicator affects following input code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53272650/2410359) may be useful.

---

> May I check `ferror(f)` after all operations and get `errno` then if I am sure that all those "do something with c" do not change `errno`?

`errno` not that useful here.  C does not specify any I/O functions as certainly setting `errno` - that is an extension of some compilers.  C expressly prohibits standard functions from clearing `errno`.

Yes, code can check `ferror(f)` to see if an error had occurred sometime in the past.  Examination of `errno` is not needed.

---

To clear both *error indicator* and *end-of-file*, research `clearer()`.