# How a stream error indicator affects following input code?

Tags: c, error-handling, language-lawyer

Each stream has "an *error indicator* that records whether a read/write error has occurred".

It is set, usually rarely, by various functions: `fgetc(), fflush(), fseek(), ...`.

It is cleared by various functions: `rewind(), clearerr(), fopen(), ...`.

`int ferror(FILE *stream)` reports the state.

> The `ferror` function returns nonzero if and only if the error indicator is set for `stream`.

---

In this case, certainly an *input error just occurred.*

```
if (!ferror(istream)) {
  int ch = fgetc(istream);
  if (ch == EOF && ferror(istream)) {
    puts("Input error just occurred");
  }
}
```

---

Exploring `fgetc()` deeper, `fgetc()` does not return `EOF` because the *error indicator* was set, but because "If a read error occurs" or end-of-file related reasons<sup>1</sup>.  Usually once an error occurs (e. g. parity error on a serial stream), code does not continue reading without clearing the error, yet consider what happens when it does continue.

I see 8 situations: the *error indicator* set/clear prior to `fgetc()`, `fgetc()` returns `EOF` or not, and a following `ferror()` could be true or not.

```
int e1 = !!ferror(istream);
int eof = fgetc(istream) == EOF;
int e2 = !!ferror(istream);
```

Assuming no UB, **are 5 of the 8 possible and not the 3 unexpected ones?** especially is **valid input possible with error indicator set?**  <sup>2</sup>

```
e1 eof e2  
0  0   0   Normal reading of valid data    
0  0   1   Unexpected
0  1   0   End-of-file
0  1   1   Input error
1  0   0   Unexpected
1  0   1   Normal reading of valid data with error indicator set!
1  1   0   Unexpected
1  1   1   Input error or end-of-file
```

---

With the *error indicator* set prior to an input operation, things become complicated and clearing it beforehand simplifies code.  Yet that prevents *error indicator* accumulation.

If codes does not clear the *error indicator* before hand and wants to detect if a *line* of input had a rare input error, it seems to make sense to test `!feof()` and not `ferror()` to detect.

**Is checking `ferror()` potentially misleading?** or have I missed something about the *error indicator*?

```
char buf[80];
for (int i=0; i<(80-1); i++) {
  int ch = fgetc(stdin);
  if (ch == EOF) {
    if (ferror(stdin)) {
      puts("Input error or (Prior input error and end of file occurred)");  // ambiguous
    } 
    if (feof(stdin)) { 
      puts("End of file occurred");
    } else {
      puts("Input error occurred");  // ferror() test not needed
      i = 0; // ignore prior input
    }
    break;
  }
  if (ch == '\n') break;
  buf[i++] = ch; 
}
buf[i] = 0;
```

---

Similar questions

[File operations with error indicator set](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35622630/2410359)
.  This unanswered one centers on accumulating *error indicator* without testing `fgetc()` return value (answers venture off into `errno` and making a user error flag) and this one is trying to simply disambiguate a `fgetc()`.

[fgetc(): Is it enough to just check EOF?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4292729/2410359) does not address *error indicator* set prior to `fgetc()`.

Similar issues apply to output and I/O streams, yet this question focuses on input streams.

---

<sup>1</sup> `int fgetc(FILE *stream)` Returns

> If the end-of-file indicator for the stream is set, or if the stream is at end-of-file, the end-of-file indicator for the stream is set and the `fgetc` function returns `EOF`. Otherwise, the fgetc function returns the next character from the input stream pointed to by `stream`. If a read error occurs, the error indicator for the stream is set and the `fgetc` function returns `EOF`.  C11dr §7.21.7.1 2

<sup>2</sup> On cases 0-1-0, 1-1-1.  Seems if `UCHAR_MAX == UINT_MAX`, a `unsigned char`, could be returned and equate to `EOF` and not be due to end-of-file nor input error.

Comment: Are you looking for a standards-based answer (perhaps [tag:language-lawyer]), or a practical answer?

Comment: @NominalAnimal Closer to standards-based than only practical as I am trying to divine the _error indicator_ mysteries to solve: when `fgetc()` returns `EOF`, is that due to a recent error, end-of-file, some wide `unsigned char` or _something else_?  LL added.

Comment: FWIW, with glibc it is always either due to detecting a new end-of-file or error condition, since the `fgetc()`/`getc()`/`getchar()` functions never examine the error flag.

Comment: @NominalAnimal Does glibc also return `EOF` on existing end-of-file flag and not just a new end-of-file?

Comment: No, it does not check for existing end-of-file flag. It will try to read more from the stream. (This also means that even if `ferror()` or `feof()` returns nonzero, the last call to `fgetc()`/`getc()`/`getchar()` did not necessarily fail; the condition could have occurred earlier.)

Comment: @NominalAnimal Hmmm, ["does not check for existing end-of-file flag"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53272650/how-a-stream-error-indicator-affects-following-input-code#comment93429969_53272650) appears non-complaint with C11 §7.21.7.1 2.  As able, please link the reference or sample source code to support that non-check.

Comment: glibc `fgetc()` is implemented in [libio/getc.c:_IO_getc()](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=libio/getc.c;hb=HEAD). The only check done is `CHECK_FILE(handle)` implemented in [libio/libioP.h](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=libio/libioP.h;hb=HEAD#l739) as a macro, and is usually optimized out. _IO_getc_unlocked() expands in [libio/libio.h](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=libio/libio.h;hb=HEAD) into [libio/bits/types/struct_FILE.h:__getc_unlocked_body()](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=libio/bits/types/struct_FILE.h;hb=HEAD) ...

Comment: which is either a direct cache lookup, or a call to [libio/genops.c:__uflow()](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=libio/genops.c;hb=HEAD). _IO_UFLOW() resolves a goto to __uflow().  I don't see any checks anywhere there.

Comment: As to EOF, compile and run the following: `#include <stdio.h>`
`int main(void) { int c; do { c = fgetc(stdin); if (c == EOF) printf("EOF\n"); } while (c != '.'); return 0; }`. A full stop `.` will end the program. Pressing Ctrl+D at the start of a line prints the EOF line. You can press it multiple times: shows EOF is not cached (except by `feof()`, of course: that does remember if EOF has been seen). I'll check if EINTR causes ferror(), and if so, will add an "answer" here with a full replication program.

Comment: Yup; verified in Linux on AMD64/x86-64 using embedded GNU C library version 2.23-0ubuntu10 in Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS. Verification program posted as an "answer".

Comment: The behavior of glibc `fgetc` was changed in version 2.28, see https://www.sourceware.org/ml/libc-alpha/2018-08/msg00003.html and https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=1190 .  We sure thought 7.21.7p2,3 mandated "sticky EOF" -- the change is described as "correct[ing] a long-standing C99 conformance bug".  (However, the EOF indicator and the error indicator are two separate bits.)

Comment: @zwol I've researched [@Nominal Animal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53272650/how-a-stream-error-indicator-affects-following-input-code?noredirect=1#comment93487805_53272650) sample code and answer below.  IMO, the functionality 1) seems non-conforming 2) With valid data keyboard input after the ^d,`fgetc()` _clears_ the end-of-file flag! 3) Still researching.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Assuming no UB, are 5 of the 8 possible and not the 3 unexpected ones?
>   especially is valid input possible with error indicator set?

Speaking specifically to the provisions of the standard, I'm inclined to agree with your analysis:

- **Few functions are specified to clear the error indicator of a stream, and `fgetc()` is not one of them**.  More generally, none of them are data-transfer functions.  Therefore, if the error indicator is set for a stream before that stream is presented to `fgetc()` for reading, then it should still be set when that function returns, all other considerations notwithstanding.  That covers these cases:<sup>*</sup>

  ```
  1  0   0   Unexpected
  1  1   0   Unexpected
  1  1   1   Input error or end-of-file
  ```

  It also covers this case with respect to the expected value of the error indicator, though it does not speak to whether it can actually happen:

  ```
  1  0   1   Normal reading of valid data with error indicator set!
  ```
- **`fgetc()` is specified to return `EOF` in every situation in which it is specified to set the end-of-file indicator on a stream**.  Therefore, if `fgetc()` returns anything other than `EOF` then it will not, on that call, have set the stream's error (or end-of-file) indicator.  That covers these cases:

  ```
  0  0   0   Normal reading of valid data    
  0  0   1   Unexpected
  ```

  On the other hand, if `fgetc()` *does* return `EOF` then either the stream's end-of-file indicator or its error indicator should afterward be found set.  But the standard distinguishes between these cases, and specifies that the user can distinguish them via the `feof()` and `ferror()` functions.  That covers these cases:<sup>*</sup>

  ```
  0  1   0   End-of-file
  0  1   1   Input error
  ```
- Finally, I concur that **none of the behavior of `fgetc()` is conditioned on the initial state of the stream's error indicator**.  Provided only that the stream is not initially positioned at its end, and its end-of-file indicator is not initially set, "the `fgetc` function returns the next character from the input stream pointed to by stream."  That establishes that this, the case of most interest, is in fact allowed:

  ```
  1  0   1   Normal reading of valid data with error indicator set!
  ```

  **However**, that the case is allowed in the abstract does not imply that it can be observed in practice.  The details seem unspecified, and I would expect them to depend on the implementation of the driver serving the stream in question.  It is entirely possible that having once encountered an error, the driver will continue to report an error on subsequent reads until reset appropriately, and perhaps longer.  From the C perspective, that would be interpreted as an (additional) error occurring on each subsequent read, and nothing in the language specifications prevents that.  Not even use of one of the functions that clear a stream's error indicator.

> If codes does not clear the *error indicator* before hand and wants to
>   detect if a line of input had a rare input error, it seems to make
>   sense to test `!feof()` and not `ferror()` to detect.
>
> **Is checking `ferror()` potentially misleading?** or have I missed something about the *error indicator*?

I agree that if a stream's error indicator is initially set, its end-of-file indicator is not, and reading it with `fgetc()` returns `EOF`, then `ferror()` does not usefully distinguish between the end-of-file and error cases whereas `feof()` should.

On the other hand, whether one can usefully continue to read a given stream after an error has been encountered on it depends on implementation and possibly on specific circumstances.  That applies even if the error indicator is cleared via a `clearerr()` call, not to mention if the error indicator is *not* cleared.

---

<sup>*</sup> Although I agree that there is an ambiguity with respect to `EOF` in the event that `UCHAR_MAX > INT_MAX`, I assert that that is just one of several reasons why such an implementation would be problematic.  As a practical matter, therefore, I disregard such implementations as entirely hypothetical.

Comment: Additional interest in "usefully continue to read a given stream after an error has been encountered" comes from reviewing input functions for robustness. Example: [my_getline()](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/206811/29485). Such functions, when called, may or may not have the _error indicator_ set. It is outside the function's control to prevent being called when a prior error had been encountered - just like `fgetc()`. Detection of input error seems to better rely on `c == EOF && !feof(stdin)` than `c == EOF && ferror(...)`, so I was seeking other good ideas concerning _input error_.

Comment: @chux, I agree that having performed `int c = fgetc(s);` in a conforming C implementation, without knowledge of the initial state of stream `s`, testing for an error on that read via `c == EOF && !feof(s)` is valid, and it is more reliable than its analog involving `ferror`.  If `ferror` is to be used instead, then the stream's error indicator must first be ensured clear.  I am unaware of any alternatives  fundamentally different from these.

Answer (score 1):

Everything you say seems right, and `ch==EOF && !feof(f)` is the right way to check for new errors without interfering with error accumulation.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very crude, very minimal program to explore the behaviour of GNU C library with respect to `fgetc()`, `ferror()`, and `feof()`, as requested by OP in a comment:

```
#define  _POSIX_C_SOURCE  200809L
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <errno.h>

static volatile sig_atomic_t  interrupted = 0;

static void interrupt_handler(int signum)
{
    interrupted = 1;
}

static int install_interrupt(const int signum)
{
    struct sigaction  act;

    memset(&act, 0, sizeof act);
    sigemptyset(&act.sa_mask);
    act.sa_handler = interrupt_handler;
    act.sa_flags = 0;
    if (sigaction(signum, &act, NULL) == -1)
        return -1;

    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    int  n, c;

    if (install_interrupt(SIGALRM)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot install SIGALRM handler: %s.\n", strerror(errno));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if (ferror(stdin)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Standard input is already in error state.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    if (feof(stdin)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Standard input is already in end-of-input state.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    fprintf(stderr, "Testing stream error state. Please wait.\n");

    alarm(1);
    c = fgetc(stdin);
    if (c != EOF) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Stream error state test failed.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    fprintf(stderr, "fgetc(stdin) returned EOF.\n");
    fprintf(stderr, "ferror(stdin) returns %d.\n", ferror(stdin));
    fprintf(stderr, "feof(stdin) returns %d.\n", feof(stdin));

    fprintf(stderr, "\n");
    fprintf(stderr, "Testing stream end-of-input state. Please press Ctrl+D.\n");
    c = fgetc(stdin);
    if (c != EOF) {
        fprintf(stderr, "fgetc() returned %d; EOF was expected.\n", c);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "fgetc(stdin) returned EOF.\n");
    fprintf(stderr, "ferror(stdin) returns %d.\n", ferror(stdin));
    fprintf(stderr, "feof(stdin) returns %d.\n", feof(stdin));
    if (!ferror(stdin) || !feof(stdin)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Expected error and end-of-file states; aborting.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    fprintf(stderr, "\n");
    fprintf(stderr, "Testing fgetc() when stream in error and end-of-file state.\n");
    fprintf(stderr, "Please type something, then press Enter.\n");
    n = 0;
    c = fgetc(stdin);
    while (c != EOF && c != '\n') {
        n++;
        c = fgetc(stdin);
    }
    if (c == EOF) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Further input is not possible.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    } else
        fprintf(stderr, "Further input is possible: %d characters (including Enter) read.\n", n + 1);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

When I compile and run the above on Linux, the program will output

```
Testing stream error state. Please wait.
fgetc(stdin) returned EOF.
ferror(stdin) returns 1.
feof(stdin) returns 0.
```

The error state was caused by having signal delivery interrupt an `fgetc(stdin)` call. As you can see, it does cause `ferror(stdin)` to return nonzero. Note that `feof(stdin)` returns 0, though.

The output continues:

```
Testing stream end-of-input state. Please press Ctrl+D.
```

Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> yields output

```
fgetc(stdin) returned EOF.
ferror(stdin) returns 1.
feof(stdin) returns 1.
```

At this point, the standard input is in both error and end-of-file states. The output continues:

```
Testing fgetc() when stream in error and end-of-file state.
Please type something, then press Enter.
```

If we now type say <kbd>O</kbd> <kbd>K</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>, we get

```
Further input is possible: 3 characters (including Enter) read.
```

This proves that at least the GNU C library implementation does not check the stream error or end-of-file status at all. It will simply try to read more data (using the underlying `read()` operation in POSIXy systems).

Comment: I also found similar results, yet tend to think it is non-conforming to the standard.  (IOWs, a bug in that version).  I also noticed that the end-of-file flag was cleared by  `fgetc()` call with 5 key  `"x\n"`, Ctrl d, `".\n"` sequence with  the `'.'` key.

Comment: @chux: On POSIXy systems, the EOF behaviour kinda makes sense, because if the file gets appended to after we read it till the end, we'll want to get the appended data; and since there is no `cleareof()` function, reopening the file would be the only way to do that otherwise.  Whether any of this is standards-conformant, I have no opinion: I've decided to steer away from language-lawyer. (If it is a bug in glibc, getting it fixed is a quixotic fight against people who believe they know the standards better than anyone else. Not worth the effort, IMO.)

Comment: Re: "there is no `cleareof()`".  Would not `clearerr(istream)` be sufficient in lieu of  reopening the file?  IAC, thanks for the exploring the corners of C I/O.

Comment: @NominalAnimal For the record, if you believe you have found a bug in glibc and you don't feel like arguing with Joseph and/or Paul Eggert about it, you can email me and I'll do it.  Ulrich is no longer involved.

Comment: @zwol: Yeah, [libio/getc.c:_IO_getc()](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=libio/getc.c;hb=HEAD) and libio/getc_u.c:__getc_unlocked() are still missing an `_IO_ferror_unlocked()` check in HEAD. I'd recommend turning `_IO_getc_unlocked()` into a function that does the check, and returns `__getc_unlocked_body()`. Also, an RFC to the devs: perhaps change `_IO_EOF_SEEN` in libio/bits/types/struct_FILE.h to `0x0030`, so that `feof()` returns nonzero if eof or error.

Comment: @NominalAnimal Thanks.  I will dig into that more on the weekend.  As John Bollinger points out, the standard doesn't require a sticky _error_ indicator, though, just a sticky _EOF_ indicator.  `_IO_EOF_SEEN` cannot be changed without breaking the ABI, I think, but there's probably something else we could do with the same effect.

Comment: @zwol: No worries, 'twas only a suggestion. IMHO the standard is then bass-ackwards: there is no practical need for *EOF* to be sticky, but if *error* is not sticky, then there is a real risk of accidentally missing errors. I so wish there were more software engineers and fewer computer scientists (and company representatives) among the C standard developers; to bridge the gap between theory and practice.

Answer (score 1):

My reading of the standard is that it doesn't explicitly say `fgetc` is allowed to return a non-`EOF` value if the error indicator was already set on the stream on entry, but it doesn't explicitly say that it *can't*, either.  I sympathize with Nominal Animal's observation (which I shall hoist from comments on his answer in case it gets deleted or moved to chat; allow me to grind my personal axe for a moment and observe that the policy of treating comments as "ephemeral" is harmful and should be abolished):

> IMHO the standard is then bass-ackwards: there is no practical need for EOF to be sticky, but if error is not sticky, then there is a real risk of accidentally missing errors.

However, if existing implementations are all consistently not treating error as sticky, changing the behavior will be very hard to sell to the committee.  Therefore, I am soliciting tests from the community:

Below is a shortened, non-interactive version of [Nominal Animal's test program](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53304321/388520).  It only looks at the behavior of `fgetc` after a read error, not after EOF.  It uses `SIGALRM` to interrupt a read, instead of control-C, so you don't have to do anything but run it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static _Noreturn void
perror_exit (const char *msg)
{
  perror (msg);
  exit (1);
}

static void
handler (int unused)
{
}

int
main (void)
{
  struct sigaction sa;
  int pipefd[2];
  FILE *fp;
  int ch, pa;

  setvbuf (stdout, 0, _IOLBF, 0);

  sa.sa_handler = handler;
  sa.sa_flags = 0; /* DO interrupt blocking system calls */
  sigemptyset (&sa.sa_mask);
  if (sigaction (SIGALRM, &sa, 0))
    perror_exit ("sigaction");

  if (pipe (pipefd))
    perror_exit ("pipe");

  fp = fdopen (pipefd[0], "r");
  if (!fp)
    perror_exit ("fdopen");

  printf ("before fgetc 1, feof = %d ferror = %d\n",
          feof (fp), ferror (fp));

  alarm (1);
  ch = fgetc (fp);

  if (ch == EOF)
    printf ("after fgetc 1, ch = EOF feof = %d ferror = %d\n",
            feof (fp), ferror (fp));
  else
    printf ("after fgetc 1, ch = '%c' feof = %d ferror = %d\n",
            ch, feof (fp), ferror (fp));

  write (pipefd[1], "x", 1);
  alarm (1);
  ch = fgetc (fp);
  pa = alarm (0);

  printf ("after fgetc 2, alarm %s\n",
          pa ? "did not fire" : "fired");

  if (ch == EOF)
    printf ("after fgetc 2, ch = EOF feof = %d ferror = %d\n",
            feof (fp), ferror (fp));
  else
    printf ("after fgetc 2, ch = '%c' feof = %d ferror = %d\n",
            ch, feof (fp), ferror (fp));

  return 0;
}
```

On all of the Unixes I can get at at the moment, this program's output is consistent with John Bollinger's observation that

> the case of most interest, is in fact allowed:
>
> ```
> 1  0   1   Normal reading of valid data with error indicator set!
> ```

I would particularly like to know what this program prints when run on alternative Linux-based C libraries (e.g. musl, bionic); Unixes which are not Linux nor are they BSD-phylum; and Windows.  If you've got anything even more exotic please try that too.  I'm marking this post community wiki; please edit it to add test results.

The test program should be acceptable to any C89-compliant compiler for an environment where `unistd.h` exists and `signal.h` defines `sigaction`, except for one use of the C11 `_Noreturn` keyword which is only to squelch warnings.  If your compiler complains about `_Noreturn`, compile with `-D_Noreturn=`; the results will not be affected.  If you don't have `unistd.h`, the test program will not do anything meaningful in your environment.  If you don't have `sigaction` you *may* be able to adapt the program to use alternative interfaces, but you need to persuade `SIGALRM` to interrupt a blocking `read` somehow.

### Results

```
before fgetc 1, feof = 0 ferror = 0
after fgetc 1, ch = EOF feof = 0 ferror = 1
after fgetc 2, alarm did not fire
after fgetc 2, ch = 'x' feof = 0 ferror = 1
```

("normal reading of valid data with error indicator set")

- Linux with glibc 2.27
- NetBSD 7.1.2
- FreeBSD 11.2-RELEASE-p4
- macOS 10.14, clang-1000.10.44.2
- macOS 10.14, gcc 8.2.0 (Homebrew)

.

```
before fgetc 1, feof = 0 ferror = 0
after fgetc 1, ch = EOF feof = 0 ferror = 1
after fgetc 2, alarm did not fire
after fgetc 2, ch = EOF feof = 0 ferror = 1
```

("sticky error" behavior: `fgetc(fp)` immediately returns EOF without calling `read` when `ferror(fp)` is true on entry)

- Plan 9 (compiler does not recognize _Noreturn)

.